# Packaging Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, war, packaging, ear, java-ee-7

I need to develop three different applications. But all of them have something in common, for example users management and also some business logic. So I want to move this common part in separate jar (war?) and use it as dependency in these three projects. As far as I know, if I have multiple war in ear I can't share session between wars. So having two wars for one application seems to me not very good option. But in this common part I will have some servlets and websocket, so I should pack it into war. So I'm confused about right way to do this. Ideally, I want to assemble each application in one war, it seems to me easier than have ear and java ee 7 allows this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's any way to share sessions, and it's probably not a good idea anyway, but you could implement Single Sign On (SSO) using one of a variety of methods, and/or use domain-wide cookie, and use that information to look up information in your database.

It's usually a good idea to keep your session very light-weight, e.g. storing just a user key in session, and look up what you need in the database anyway, so this isn't much of a departure.

In this case, it wouldn't matter whether you packaged your apps as separate wars or in an ear, however, if you package it as an ear, you can share libraries among the apps without duplicating them. If you package as separate wars, you will have to include the 'shared' jars in each war.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify GreyBeardedGeek answer:

Package your common dependencies in some jars and include them in the dependent wars. (Wars are web application archives, ie. they contains classes (servlet) which will be managed by the web container and a related deployment descriptor (web.xml), a war must not be used to package dependencies).

If you want to avoid to classload the dependencies (jar) many times you can package your 3 different application (war) in the same ear and put the shared dependencies (the jars) in the ear lib directory.
 
In this case the dependencies will be classloaded at the ear level and so shared between all applications but you won't be able to use different versions of those jars in the different applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at [The Java EE 7 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/). Look at the **Case Studies** section. There are two that will interest you; (1) "Duke's Tutoring Case Study Example" and (2) "Duke's Forest Case Study Example". Both show how this is done. The latter is a simple e-commerce application that contains several web applications; Duke's Store, Duke's Shipment, Duke's Payment, Duke's Resources, Entities & Events. These can be shared among other projects.

You can get the code with [these](https://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/pages/JavaEE7TutorialFAQ#Installing_the_Tutorial_from_a_GlassFish_4.0_Install) instructions